# Different articulations of duration with different conjugations?

Tags: choix-de-mot, temps-grammatical, conjugaison, indications-de-temps

I am often asked how long I'm in Paris for, and I find myself having difficulty articulating the following three sentences. Anything may be wrong here, including choice of verb, conjugation of said verb, or preposition.

> *I'm living in Paris for two months.* --> *J'habite à Paris pendant deux mois.*
>
> *I'll be living in Paris for one more month.* --> *J'habiterai* (ou *je resterai*) *à Paris pour un mois (de plus).*
>
> *I have been living in Paris for one month. --> J'habite à Paris depuis un mois.*

Are any of these correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sentence is unidiomatic.

I'm living in Paris for two months. → *J'habite à Paris <s>pendant</s> deux mois.*

> *J'habite (ou je suis) à Paris pour deux mois.*

Your second one is acceptable if *de plus* is used, but I wouldn't say it that way.

I'll be living in Paris for one more month. → *J'habiterai (ou je resterai) à Paris pour un mois (de plus).*

> *Je vais encore habiter à Paris pendant un mois.*
>
> *Je resterai un mois de plus à Paris.*

Your third one is how I would say it too:

I have been living in Paris for one month. → *J'habite à Paris depuis un mois.*

Comment: The other answer is the total inverse of yours; this is troubling.

Comment: I believe AI Fonce is confusing "I've been living in Paris" and "I've lived in Paris".

Comment: just like he confuses "since" and "for"...